# Setting up Blackberry Project (above version 5) in Phonegap using IDE to implement push notification

Tags: blackberry, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a mobile app using phonegap for the Android, iPhone and Blackberry platforms.

I need a notification to be send from a Java EE server to BB when a new message gets created. This means the Java EE server pushes this notification and the BB mobile device gets the notification. I need to put a push notification feature in my app, so that my server can poll my app and then put the notification if there is any new notification.

On browsing the net I found out that there are plugins for Phonegap for both iPhone and Android, which help in showing the notification. But I did not find any useful resources for Blackberry.

I am following http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/30152/Push_Service_SDK-Installation_and_Configuration_Guide--1648741-0622124431-001-1.1.0.16-US.pdf.

However, I'm facing some environment challenge (setting up the SDK in the IDE for Blackberry in Phonegap).

To use that SDK the IDE is needed, but I think using ANT is not possible. I need some examples for creating the Phonegap project for Blackberry using the IDE.

I want to get a push notification in Blackberry using phonegap. Can someone help me in performing this? Any links that explain this with HTML or JavaScript would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap does not provide plugins for Blackberry. Instead BB already have an API for HTML5 for push notifications (BIS/BES). They are a bit limited comparing to the native code: for example there is no sound support.

You can use Blackberry Webworks SDK and Ripple as BB emulator. The only problem is that Ripple does not support push notifications and in the end you have to test your app on a real device anyway.

For more information take a look on the tutorial here:
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/blackberry-html5-webworks-push-notification-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether Phone Gap has the plugin to support BlackBerry.  I think Phone Gap forums might be a better place to post this question.

Thanks

Naveen M